# How to bind object with two layouts?

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding, observable

I have such Model

```
public class MyCheckedVM extends BaseObservable {
     @Bindable
ObservableBoolean observableBoolean = new ObservableBoolean();


@Bindable
public ObservableBoolean getObservableBoolean() {
    return observableBoolean;
}

@Bindable
public void setObservableBoolean(ObservableBoolean observableBoolean) {
    this.observableBoolean = observableBoolean;
}

public void onCheckChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCheckChanged");

}
```

This model I set to Main activity binding with `ToggleButton` and inside `Fragment` which has such button too

```
   <ToggleButton
    android:onCheckedChanged="@{viewModel.onCheckChanged}"
    android:checked="@{viewModel.observableBoolean}"
    android:id="@+id/toggle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

But when i try to click on any button, all of them are changing independently of each other. Maybe it is wrong way how I bind model to `Fragmnet`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  FragmentExampleBinding fragmentExampleBinding =   DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_example, container, false);

    fragmentExampleBinding.setViewModel(((MainActivity) getActivity()).getViewModel()); //getter in MainActivity for instance of viewModel

    return fragmentExampleBinding.getRoot();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem I see is your use of `setObservableBoolean`. You have a `BaseObservable` so you should notify the property change if you call a setter.

But that's only because you're using `ObservableBoolean` in an unusual manner. Best practice is to always use them as `public final` fields. If you do this, you don't need to use `BaseObservable` as a base class:

```
public class MyCheckedVM {
    public final ObservableBoolean observableBoolean = new ObservableBoolean();

    public void onCheckChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCheckChanged");
    }
}
```

You can mix observable fields in an Observable class (or BaseObservable). Just make your observable fields `public final` and make sure to call `notifyPropertyChanged(BR.myField)` inside the setters of bindable properties.

Comment: Thank you for advice! I tried the way by seting my observable boolean field  to true in onCheckedChanged to make both of them checked, however I'll make it by yours